# how do i use a multiple on taps on the same bottom navbar in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

This is my code how do i add multiple on taps so each icon take me to specific page please help me, I cant figure out how to solve it i tried inkwell i tried everything it didn't work the problem is all buttons navigate to the same page if i add navigator there because there is one ontap this is the code

how do i use multiple on taps on the same bottom navbar in flutter 0 This is my code how do i add multiple on taps so each icon take me to specific page please help me, I cant figure out how to solve it i tried inkwell i tried everything it didn't work the problem is all buttons navigate to the same page if i add navigator there because there is one ontap this is the code

```dart
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rive/rive.dart';
import 'package:rive_animation/displaypage.dart';
import 'package:rive_animation/welcome.dart';
import 'package:bottom_navy_bar/bottom_navy_bar.dart';
import '../../../model/menu.dart';
import 'animated_bar.dart';

class BtmNavItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const BtmNavItem(
      {super.key,
      required this.navBar,
      required this.press,
      required this.riveOnInit,
      required this.selectedNav});

  final Menu navBar;
  final VoidCallback press;
  final ValueChanged<Artboard> riveOnInit;
  final Menu selectedNav;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(

      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const Test()));
      },


      // },
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          AnimatedBar(isActive: selectedNav == navBar),
          SizedBox(
            height: 36,
            width: 36,
            child: Opacity(
              opacity: selectedNav == navBar ? 1 : 0.5,
              child: RiveAnimation.asset(
                navBar.rive.src,
                artboard: navBar.rive.artboard,
                onInit: riveOnInit,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),


    );
  }

}
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text(
            "NEXT PAGE",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 25,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF011230),
          elevation: 0,
        ),
        body: SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: ListView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 10, right: 20, left: 20, bottom: 5),
              children: <Widget>[
                Flex(
                  direction: Axis.horizontal,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: const Text("test 1",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            )),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 15),
                Flex(
                  direction: Axis.horizontal,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: const Text("test 2",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            )),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 15),
                Flex(
                  direction: Axis.horizontal,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: const Text("test 3",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            )),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 5),
              ],
            )));
  }
}ild: RiveAnimation.asset( navBar.rive.src, artboard: navBar.rive.artboard, onInit: riveOnInit, ), ), ), ], ), ); } }
```

i tried everything didnt work

Comment: are you using git for this project

Comment: yea i used it git

Comment: Seems you've stuck for a long time, if it is public can you share the github link,  myself `yeasin50`

Comment: you mean the githib or what

Comment: this is the github https://github.com/abuanwar072/Build-an-Animated-App-with-Rive-and-Flutter

Comment: what the file name of your `Test` widget,

Comment: yes that was it finally